# delete docker volume does not remvoe the local file

Tags: docker, nginx

I run a docker container of nginx with the following: `docker container run -d --name nginx3 -p 85:80 -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html nginx` , then when I add files in the container volume (/usr/share/nginx/html) they are also added locally on the $pwd folder.

But when I remove the container, image, and volume with `docker rm -vf $(docker ps -aq) && docker rmi -f $(docker images -aq) && docker volume prune` the files on my local $pwd folder are still there.. why were they not deleted when I removed the volume?

Answer (score 2):

That's because docker volume prune delete the docker volumes and not the mounted volumes from the host.

If you define a volume with `docker volume create nginx_volume` and then use

```
docker container run -d --name nginx3 -p 85:80 -v nginx_volume:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

the volume will be deleted

Comment: Hey, thx for the answer. so I need to create the volume separately via docker volume create <volume_name> in order for the docker volume prune to delete it?

Comment: And what is the different between mounted volumes and docker volumes?

Comment: docker volumes are like virtual folder that are not mapped on your hardisk but until they are not deleted they hold data even if your delete the container that uses it

Comment: The `docker volume` command will never delete local files no matter how you create the volume.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a docker volume, you are using a bind mount. This was not that clear with the `-v` syntax, that's why docker recommends the new `--mount` syntax for new users:

This creates a bind mount from the host OS. Docker is not owner of it and therefore not deleting the folder if you unmount the binding.

```
 docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

[Further reading](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

This creates a docker volume, which is managed by docker. And therefore all volume-commands can be applied:

```
 docker run -d \
  --name devtest \
  --mount source=myvol2,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

[Further reading](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)